# Filter list and print whole name containing string python

Tags: python, list, filter

I am trying to filter a list in python.
What i need is a way to limit what is beeing printed out from the list

Example:
I want to find all subjects containing "ECON"
from this list:

```
List = ["INFO100","INFO104","INFO110","INFO150","INFO125","ECON100", "ECON102"]
```

And i want to be able to print out the full name of the objects containing "ECON" (that means i want it to return "ECON100", "ECON102")
is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: As stated in the duplicate: `[s for s in List if 'ECON' in s]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for sub_string in List:
   if "ECON" in sub_string:
      print(sub_string)
```